# Laravel 8 (PHP) & Google Cloud Speech API: Streaming calls are not supported while using the REST transport.)

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text

Wassup Guys,

I've managed to install the Google Cloud Speech Api and use my .json file as credentials for the speech client.

Now I'm getting the "Streaming calls are not supported while using the REST transport."
error.

Did I miss something? Below is the method of my controller.
AudioController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Google\Cloud\Speech\V1\RecognitionConfig\AudioEncoding;
use Google\Cloud\Speech\V1\RecognitionConfig;
use Google\Cloud\Speech\V1\StreamingRecognitionConfig;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Google\Cloud\Speech\V1\SpeechClient;


class AudioController extends Controller
{
    public function getData(Request $request)
    {
        //$url = Storage::download('public/track.mp3');
        $url = asset('storage/test.flac');

        //$file = Storage::disk('public')->get('track.mp3');
        //$download = new Response($file, 200);


        // dd($request->all(), $url);
        return view('welcome')->with('downloadLink', $url);
    }

    public function transcribedText(Request $request)
    {

        $recognitionConfig = new RecognitionConfig();
        $recognitionConfig->setEncoding(AudioEncoding::FLAC);
        $recognitionConfig->setSampleRateHertz(44100);
        $recognitionConfig->setLanguageCode('en-US');
        $config = new StreamingRecognitionConfig();
        $config->setConfig($recognitionConfig);
        $auth = Storage::disk('public')->get('auth.json');
        $test = Storage::path('public/auth.json');
        //dd(file_get_contents($test, true));
        //dd(json_decode($auth));
        //putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.$auth);
        $speechClient = new SpeechClient([
            'credentials' => Storage::path('public/auth.json'),
        ]);
        $file = Storage::disk('public')->get('test.flac');


        // $audioResource = fopen('path/to/audio.flac', 'r');

        $responses = $speechClient->recognizeAudioStream($config, $file);

        foreach ($responses as $element) {
            dd($element);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure gRPC for PHP is installed and enabled.

Check your php.ini file for:

**extension=grpc.so** - Linux.

**extension=php_grpc.dll** - Windows.

Add the composer dependency:

```
composer require "grpc/grpc:^1.38"
```

[Install gRPC for PHP](https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc)

Comment: I am using Laravel inside a docker container through Laravel Sail. Do I have to install the gRPC Package inside the shell or what is exactly the approach for this?

Comment: @LaFllamme The steps are the same for php.ini and composer. I do not use Sail, so I am not sure how you copy/install php.ini for that service. Since Sail is based upon Docker, I assume that you would set up your container and test/verify locally. Then deploy the container (or the container Dockerfile) to Sail. This article might help: https://hackernoon.com/what-is-wrong-with-laravel-sail-78s314m

Answer (score 0):

For anyone encountering the same issue:

Laravel Sail uses a regular Dockerfile under Vendor/Sail folder and and also a php.ini in the same drirectory, that gets copied after building.

Just add this for phar:
&& apt-get install autoconf zlib1g-dev php-pear \

RUN curl -O https://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
RUN php go-pear.phar
RUN pecl install grpc -q

And this to the php.ini
extension=grpc.so